# How to set auto height in MVC ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, height, reportviewer

How to set MVCReportViewer autosizing height. I tried SizeToReportContent, AsyncRendering, ZoomMode, AutoSize. I changed .aspx xhtml to html. Nothing worked.

```
@Html.MvcReportViewer(Model.ReportPath).Attributes(new { height = "100%", width = "100%", style = "border: none;", AsyncRendering = "true", SizeToReportContent = "true"}).ControlSettings(settings)
```